# Group records that are created max 20 sec from each other - MySql

Tags: mysql

I need to sum ONLY the values of the records that are created in the same timeframe (for example max 10 seconds difference).

This is an example table, record 1&2 must be added, 3&4, and so on.  But only if the difference is less than 10 seconds, otherwise they must stay in separate records.

Can this be done in mysql?

| Year | Month | Day | Time | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 10 | 17 | 15:53:38 | -1 |
| 2021 | 10 | 17 | 15:53:35 | -10 |
| 2021 | 10 | 14 | 08:29:04 | -2 |
| 2021 | 10 | 14 | 08:29:02 | -3 |
| 2021 | 10 | 9 | 12:21:22 | -10 |
| 2021 | 10 | 9 | 12:34:20 | -5 |
| 2021 | 9 | 26 | 10:22:30 | -2 |
| 2021 | 9 | 26 | 10:22:28 | -3 |
| 2021 | 9 | 24 | 04:14:26 | -2 |
| 2021 | 9 | 24 | 04:14:24 | -9 |
| 2021 | 9 | 19 | 20:08:47 | -9 |
| 2021 | 9 | 19 | 20:08:42 | -2 |
| 2021 | 9 | 5 | 14:49:18 | -3 |
| 2021 | 9 | 5 | 14:49:16 | -2 |
| 2021 | 8 | 8 | 14:17:55 | -1 |
| 2021 | 8 | 8 | 14:17:53 | -4 |
| 2021 | 7 | 26 | 19:12:21 | -2 |

Comment: I've removed the 2 tags and replaced it with [[tag:sql]]. [[tag:tsql]] is the dialect SQL Server uses, not MySQL. [Edit] your question to tag the *actual* RDBMS you are using. You mention T-SQL in the actual question, so that suggests you *are* using SQl Server, not MySQl.

Comment: That `Time` field - is it an actual time or a text field with a string in it that looks like a time?

Comment: Time field is varchar(15)

Comment: (it's mysql so i changed the question)

Comment: If the times are 12:00:00, 12:00:15, 12:00:19, 12:00:25 how should they be grouped?

Comment: @forpas: if one of the x times is displayed it's ok. The time is not that important

Comment: My question is: will 12:00:00, 12:00:15 and 12:00:19 belong to 1 group and 12:00:25 to a separate group? Or, 12:00:00 in 1 group and 12:00:15, 12:00:19 and 12:00:25 to another group, or any other combination of groups.

Comment: they will be in one group but the max records will be 2 records in that time frame.  (there are 2 systems sending records to the database and they differ in time)

Answer (score 0):

This a far too late to be of use to OP, but in case it is of use to someone else in the future, here is one approach.

To handle scenarios where the time diff spans two different days, or even different years:

| Year | Month | Day | Time | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | 01 | 01 | 00:00:02 | -1 |
| 2021 | 12 | 31 | 23:59:59 | -10 |
| 2021 | 10 | 19 | 00:00:02 | -2 |
| 2021 | 10 | 18 | 23:59:59 | -3 |

We need to work with the full date time values.

If using **MySQL >= 8.0** we can use the [`LAG()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lag) window function to access the previous rows values, and group by the running total of whether the diff is less than 10 seconds:

```sql
WITH timeDiffs AS (
    SELECT CAST(CONCAT(`Year`, '-', `Month`, '-', `Day`, ' ', `Time`) AS DATETIME) AS `dt`, `Value`,
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(
            SECOND,
            LAG(CAST(CONCAT(`Year`, '-', `Month`, '-', `Day`, ' ', `Time`) AS DATETIME)) OVER (ORDER BY `Year`, `Month`, `Day`, `Time`),
            CAST(CONCAT(`Year`, '-', `Month`, '-', `Day`, ' ', `Time`) AS DATETIME)
        ) AS secDiff
    FROM tbl
),
timeGroups AS (
    SELECT *, SUM(secDiff >= 10 OR secDiff IS NULL) OVER (ORDER BY `dt`) AS grp
    FROM timeDiffs
)
SELECT
    EXTRACT(YEAR   FROM MIN(`dt`)) AS `Year`,
    EXTRACT(MONTH  FROM MIN(`dt`)) AS `Month`,
    EXTRACT(DAY    FROM MIN(`dt`)) AS `Day`,
    TIME(MIN(`dt`)) AS `Time`,
    SUM(`Value`) AS `Value`
FROM timeGroups
GROUP BY grp;
```

The first CTE returns the datetime (`Year`, `Month`, `Day` & `Time` combined), `Value` and difference between current row's datetime and previous row's datetime, in seconds.

The second CTE creates a running count on whether the diff is greater than 10 seconds, which we then use in the final select for grouping.

---

If using **MySQL < 8.0** we can use a similar approach, but using user defined variables instead:

```sql
SELECT
    EXTRACT(YEAR   FROM MIN(`dt`)) AS `Year`,
    EXTRACT(MONTH  FROM MIN(`dt`)) AS `Month`,
    EXTRACT(DAY    FROM MIN(`dt`)) AS `Day`,
    TIME(MIN(`dt`)) AS `Time`,
    SUM(`Value`) AS `Value`
FROM (
    SELECT `dt`, `Value`,
        @grp := @grp + IF(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, @pDateTime, dt) < 10, 0, 1) AS grp,
        (@pDateTime := dt) AS vars
    FROM (
        SELECT CAST(CONCAT(`Year`, '-', `Month`, '-', `Day`, ' ', `Time`) AS DATETIME) AS `dt`, `Value`
        FROM tbl
        JOIN (SELECT @pDateTime := NULL, @grp := 0) udv
        ORDER BY `Year`, `Month`, `Day`, `Time`
    ) t1
) t2
GROUP BY grp;
```

Note that ([8.0.13 release notes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-13.html#mysqld-8-0-13-deprecation-removal)):

> ***Important Change:*** Setting user variables in statements other than SET is now deprecated due to issues that included those listed here:
>
> - The order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables was undefined.
> - The default result type of a variable is based on its type at the beginning of the statement, which could have unintended effects when a variable holding a value of one type at the beginning of a statement was assigned a new value of a different type in the same statement.
> - HAVING, GROUP BY, and ORDER BY clauses, when referring to a variable that was assigned a value in the select expression list, did not work as expected because the expression was evaluated on the client and so it was possible for stale column values from a previous row to be used.
>
> Syntax such as SELECT @var, @var:=@var+1 is still accepted in MySQL 8.0 for backward compatibility, but is subject to removal in a future MySQL version. (WL #12131)

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/29zDKBiT).